# how to control page screen height based on TabBarView's GridView itemCount?

Tags: flutter, gridview

I do have a problem in my user profile screen, I am setting it's height to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`. However, I want to based my user profile screen in my TabBarView's content since it is dynamic.

The Green Color = Scaffold's backgroundColor.

The Red Color = TabBarView's backgroundColor.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 // I am returning the StreamBuilder to fetch the data of the user
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: streamListener,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final userDetails = snapshot.data;
            return Scaffold(
              extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
// this is my reference (color) for my page screen height
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              floatingActionButton: const CreatePostActionButton(),
              appBar: CustomAppBar(
                appBarActionIcon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                showActionIcon: true,
                leading: false,
                title: userDetails["userUniqueHandle"],
                onMenuActionTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
                  );
                },
              ),
              body: SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 2.5.h,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.5.w, right: 2.5.w),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            // give the tab bar a height [can change hhight to preferred height]
                            Container(
                              height: 35,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                  25.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: TabBar(
                                controller: _tabController,
                                // give the indicator a decoration (color and border radius)
                                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    25.0,
                                  ),
                                  color: const Color(0xFF6949FF),
                                ),
                                labelColor: Colors.white,
                                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                                tabs: const [
                                  // first tab [you can add an icon using the icon property]
                                  Tab(
                                    text: 'Images',
                                  ),
                                  // second tab [you can add an icon using the icon property]
                                  Tab(
                                    text: 'Videos',
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            // tab bar view here
                            SizedBox(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                              child: TabBarView(
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                controller: _tabController,
                                children: [
                                  // first tab bar view widget
                                  StreamBuilder<List<UserActivityModel>>(
                                      stream: FirestoreHelper.readCurrentUser("posts", "posts"),
                                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                          return const Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                          );
                                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                          return const Center(
                                            child: Text("An error has occured while fetching users post."),
                                          );
                                        } else if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                                          return const Text(
                                            "You haven't posted yet, create one and you'll see it here!",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          );
                                        } else {
                                          // * this return below is actually working and fetching the posts of the current user.
                                          // return Text("mayroong data teh, mga ${snapshot.data!.length} ganon.", textAlign: TextAlign.center,);
                                          final currentUserImages = snapshot.data;
                                          return Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
// color of tabbarview area where it contains the images i fetched from db.
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                                child: GridView.builder(
                                                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                                  //itemCount: images.length,
                                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                                  itemCount: currentUserImages!.length,
                                                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                                                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                                                  ),
                                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                                    final fetchUserImages = currentUserImages[index];
                                                    List<String>? tempFile = fetchUserImages.feelsImages;
                                                    List<String> saveFile = [];
                                                    for (var i in tempFile!) {
                                                      saveFile.add(i);
                                                    }
                                                    return CachedNetworkImage(
                                                      imageUrl: saveFile.first,
                                                      placeholder: (context, url) => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          );
                                        }
                                      }),
                                  const Text(
                                    'Staggered Videos Should be here.',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 25,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        });
  }
```

here is the sample image of the ui that I am currently working on.

[image]